# Change jQuery's animation duration during animating

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-animate, state, duration

Is it possible to change the `duration` of a currently running jQuery animation between two different values?

I've tried to change the `duration` via direct assignment, but no success:

```
var timing = { duration: 4000 };
$(document).click(function (e) {
  timing.duration = 1000;
});

$('#foo').animate({top:200, left:200}, timing);
```

...and even, changing the `fx.options.duration` in `step`-method does not affect the running animation:

```
var state = false,
$(document).click(function (e) {
  state = true;
});

$('#foo').animate({top:200, left:200}, {
  duration: 4000,
  step: function(now, fx){
    if(state) fx.options.duration = 1000;
    console.log(fx.options.duration); // 1000
  }
});
```

Here's a **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5cdwc/)** to play around.
Any ideas how this can be done?

Comment: If you switch from jQuery 2.0 to jQuery >= 1.7.2 it (somewhat) works. I guess it has to do with the recent changes the jQuery team did on the animation related functions.

Comment: @Mahn Yeah, thanks! I've noticed that... I'm in the core now, try to figure out how to fiddle that out!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The duration is passed by value, not by reference. So `animate` does not store a reference to `duration`. Even if you update the options object (which is passed by reference) jQuery uses `options.duration` internally, which means it will be passed by value.

As a quick fix you could stop the animation and restart it with the new duration - adjusting for the part of the animation that is already over.

You'd need to consider how you want it to behave, for example when you speed up a 4 second animation to a 2 second animation after 3 seconds. In the code below the animation will be immediate. Thinking about it, that's probably not what you want since you probably really care about speed, not duration.

The code below is a rough sketch, I'm not sure if it's accurate, if it works when decreasing animation values or how it handles multiple animation values. You can also only change the duration once.

```
var state = false,
    duration = 8000;

$(document).click(function (e) {
    state = true;
    duration = 1000;
});
var animationCss = {top:200, left:200};
$('#foo').animate(animationCss, {
    duration: duration,
    step: function(now, fx){
        if(state) {
             $("#foo").stop();
             var percentageDone = (fx.now - fx.start) / (fx.end - fx.start) 
             var durationDone = fx.options.duration * percentageDone;
             var newDuration = duration - durationDone;
            if (newDuration < 0)
            {
                 newDuration = 0;   
            }
            $("#foo").animate(animationCss, { duration: newDuration})

        }
    }
});
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/5cdwc/3/

Comment: Yeah, thanks for your thoughts and explanation! The idea is great, however I think, that there's certainly a sweeter workaround somewhere in the wild!

Comment: @yckart There's the `easing` option, but I'm not sure how it works and if you need to know the animation speed before starting the animation.

Comment: This can actually work well, as long as animationCss carry absolute values (e.g. no +=50) and depending on how you want it to behave like @Matt mentions in his answer. You can make it look pretty wrapping it in a plugin, that should be relatively easy to do.

Comment: Here's by the way a fork of Matt's code that is relative to the completed percentage rather than the absolute duration (basically the alternative behaviour): http://fiddle.jshell.net/4mFn4/

Answer (score 0):

I'm probably a bit late for op but since I ended up here while trying to do the same thing, someone else may too.

On the `start()` callback jQuery pass the animation object as argument, so you just have to keep the reference somewhere and then you can change it on the  `step()` callback.

Something like :

```
var animEnd = false; //this will be updated somewhere else 
var animObj;
$().animate({
        width: '100%'
    },
    {   
        start: function(animation){
            animObj = animation;
        },
        step: function(now, tween){
            if(!animEnd)
                //jquery set an interval of 13 but let's be safe
                animObj.duration += 30;

            //you can change the value of tween.pos aswell
        }
    }
);
```

Now the tricky part is that jQuery decide to stop or continue the animation before calling the `step()` callback. So the duration is set for the next tick and if it wasn't set big enough your animation may be stopped.
jQuery use `setInterval()` with a interval of 13 so theoretically `step()` should be called every 13ms but since nothing is guaranteed I think duration should be increased by 30ms as a minimum.
Personally I would even go for at least 100. Better have an animation that runs a bit too long (100ms is almost unnoticeable) rather than having it to stop too soon.