# Update animation speed while the animation running

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I'm doing a little horse racing animation for practice. I want to change the speed of divs every 100 miliseconds and every div must have different speeds. The following code is not working as i expected.

```
var v = setInterval(function() {

        v = Math.floor(Math.random() * (9000 - 2000 + 1)) + 2000;

        return v;

    }, 500)



$("#start").click(function () {

    $("#karauzum").animate({left: "400px"}, v, function () {

        list.push("karauzum");

    });

    $("#gelibolu").animate({left: "400px"}, v, function() {

        list.push("gelibolu");

    });

    $("#yalnizefe").animate({left: "400px"}, v, function() {

        list.push("yalnizefe");

    });

    $("#ucanoglu").animate({left: "400px"}, v, function() {

        list.push("ucanoglu");

    });
```

Btw the full page is right here: http://kilavuzbaykus.com/atyarisi.html

Comment: Returning a value from a function called with setInterval won't work. Look up callback functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery animate-Function stores the speed by value, not by reference, so you can't change it mid-execution. You can however briefly stop the animation and restart it with the new values.

You can find a nice explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14673731/4780390